# Game rejected due to parental gate issue on Apple Appstore

Tags: ios, appstore-approval, parental-control

Our game is rejected due to parental gate problem. As per official guidelines,

24.3) Apps in the Kids Category must get parental permission or use a parental gate before allowing the user to link out of the app or engage in commerce

Problem occurs when user taps on advertisement, user will be redirect to another web page, so it causes the violation of above rule.

So, In which way should I implement a parental gate in the case of ads display ?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: you put a parental gate in between the ad tap and exiting your app. If your ad framework doesn't allow you to do this then you either need to use a different framework or more likely ditch advertising (or drop the made for kids category). This category and advertising are almost mutually exclusive